# Disabling the Text property of a Checkbox control using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am able to disable a Checkbox based on a dropdown value no problem but the text stays bold.
Is there a way to get to this and disable it and "gray" it out?
This question is not a duplicate.

```
<td><asp:CheckBox id="cb1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Some Text" /></td>

function ddlChanged() {
        var enable = !($("#ddlTestsCancelled").val() == 1);
        EnableCheckBoxes(enable, $("#cb1"));
    }

function EnableCheckBoxes(enable, chk) {              
        chk.prop("disabled", enable);          
        chk.prop("checked", false);           
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is get the label element for the checkbox since ASP.Net shows the `Text` of a checkbox as a label element, and then change it's CSS color attribute to gray.

```
function EnableCheckBoxes(enable, chk) {              
        chk.prop("disabled", enable);          
        chk.prop("checked", false);    
        if(enabled === true) {
           $("label[for='<%=cb1.ClientID%>']").css("color", "black");
         }  else  {
        $("label[for='<%=cb1.ClientID%>']").css("color", "gray")
        }    
    }
```

Also, to simulate a disabled effect, you can set the opacity to something like .5 instead of changing the color attribute, and then reset it to 1 when checkbox is enabled. The code for this is as given below.

```
function EnableCheckBoxes(enable, chk) {              
        chk.prop("disabled", enable);          
        chk.prop("checked", false);    
        if(enabled === true) {
           $("label[for='<%=cb1.ClientID%>']").css("opacity", 1);
         }  else  {
        $("label[for='<%=cb1.ClientID%>']").css("opacity", .5)
        }    
    }
```

If you want to use the `chk` rather than the getting the ClientId of checkbox, then use the below version of same method.

```
function EnableCheckBoxes(enable, chk) {              
        chk.prop("disabled", enable);          
        chk.prop("checked", false);    
        if(enabled === true) {
           $("label[for='" + chk[0].id + "']").css("opacity", 1);
         }  else  {
         $("label[for='" + chk[0].id + "']").css("opacity", .5)
        }    
    }
```

Comment: The label! Didn't think of that. Good one.

Comment: That's how ASP.Net renders the text for a check box.

Comment: @Sunil You are expliciting referencing CheckBox cb1 but I need something more generic to work with the passed in variable - chk

Comment: That's easy. Let me add that. Is chk the check box element?

Comment: Just added. Look at last code snippet. I have used `opacity` CSS attribute but you could use `color` instead if you like.

Comment: @Sunil sorry but no it isn't working, I'm trying color and opacity.

Comment: you mean the color does not change?

Comment: oh my fault. `chk` is jquery object and not an element. let me change it now.

Comment: just changed it so chk is treated as a jquery object. TRY NOW.

Comment: @Sunil that works fine, thank you for your help - i'm rubbish at jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to un-bold and gray out the text of an HTML element, you can use jquery's `css()` method to dynamically apply styling as follows:

```
$("#cb1").css("font-weight", "normal");
$("#cb1").css("color", "gray");
```

Comment: I've added this to EnableCheckBoxes() function but it isn't having any effect?

Comment: @Sunil has a better answer. I did not think about the label.